# Columns with fluid width and height

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, fluid-layout

I'm having trouble making a vertical bar with 5 columns and fluid width/height. What I want is when the page shrinks the height grows so the text in each column is still in the bar.

This is what i should look like and what I have: [image: vertical bar]

Now if my screen gets smaller the text comes outside the bar and thats not what I want. Also I can't get equal column widths. There are 5 columns which should be equal over 100% width but 20% each does not work.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wizard-steps">
<div class="wizard-header float-left">Kaderings analyseaanvraag</div>
<div class="wizard-header float-left">Specificaties analyses : Type staal/stalen</div>
<div class="wizard-header float-left">Specificaties analyses : Te bepalen componenten</div>
<div class="wizard-header float-left">Specificaties analyses : Tijdschema en aantal stalen</div>
<div class="wizard-header float-left">Data-analyse</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wizard-steps {
border-radius: 3px;
border: 2px solid #a2c61c;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

#wizard-steps div {
    border-right: 2px solid #a2c61c;
    width: 19%;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

    #wizard-steps div:last-child {
        border: white;
    }

.active-step {
background-color: #a2c61c;
color: white;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**UPDATED CSS:** (Thx to Ruddy & panther)

```
#wizard-steps {
border-radius: 3px;
border: 2px solid #a2c61c;
width: 100%;
display: table;
```

}

```
#wizard-steps div {
    border-right: 2px solid #a2c61c;
    width: 19%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;   
    display: table-cell;
}

    #wizard-steps div:last-child {
        border: white;
    }

.active-step {
background-color: #a2c61c;
color: white;
}
```

Which gets me this:

[image]

Any chance of fixing when it grows, the active-step background should grow aswell? Also I have a little column on the right because of the 19%.

Comment: Something like this? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e63bhd5c/)

Comment: That is exactly what I want @Ruddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `display: table/table-cell` values for container and inner divs. And remove them heights and floats.

```
#wizard-steps {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #a2c61c;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; /* you can remove that too */
    display: table;
    /* margin: 0 auto isn't necessary when width is 100% */
}

#wizard-steps div {
    border-right: 2px solid #a2c61c;
    width: 19%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;   
    display: table-cell;
}

#wizard-steps div:last-child {
    border: white;
}

.active-step {
    background-color: #a2c61c;
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ew0ku220/

Comment: Thats how I did it (I put a comment) + 1.

Answer (score 0):

A common misconception in HTML/CSS is that "100%" means "100% of the browser window". Instead, it means "100% of the width of my parent". So you need to check what's the width of the parent of `#wizard-steps`. My guess is that is the `<body>` element which doesn't have a width - to allow it to grow to fit the content.

To fix this, you must set all parent elements to `width: 100%;`, including `<body>` and `html`:

```
body, html { width: 100%; }
```

Next, you set a height. If you do that, then an element can't grow vertically. Remove this.

Comment: What do you think, what is the `html`s and `body`s default `width`?

Comment: no, their default style is `display: block;` (and `margin` for `body`), and block elements have 100% width. No auto value is there.

Comment: @panther: I know that block elements have a default width of 100% but for some reason that I don't know the code above does change the layout.

Comment: The only one difference which is caused by adding 100% width to html and body is that body is wider (100% + 2*8px margin), so scrollbar is shown due to 16px, and divs can be a little bit wider (+3px each) so their content can be a little bit reorganised. I should update my comment answer, block elements hasn't width 100%, but `100%-margins-paddings-borders`.

Comment: @panther: If you're right (and it sounds correct to me): Why can content make the body wider than the viewport if the width is fixed?

Comment: you have viewport eg. 1280px. Without setting `with` to html&body, htmls width is 1280px, width of body id 1264 (1280-2*8 margin). When you set width: 100% to body, it has 1280px width + 2*8px margin = 1296px. HTML, as a parent of body, takes this width too, so 1296. Because of 1280px viewport you see the scrollbar (content is wider than parent, in this case than viewport).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for this one. There you can just do something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" id="wizard-steps">
<div class="col-md-2">Kaderings analyseaanvraag</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Specificaties analyses : Type staal/stalen</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Specificaties analyses : Te bepalen componenten</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Specificaties analyses : Tijdschema en aantal stalen</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Data-analyse</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Inside the container you can use .row to create new rows and [.col-md-*](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) to define a column. Changing the number will give your column another size. All columns together should not be taller than 12.

Comment: I tried using bootstrap but it collides to much with my other css. This was no option unfortunately :(